# how to link ruby in macos catalina

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

Now I am using this command to install ruby:

```
~/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open on  main! ⌚ 17:04:27
$ brew install ruby
Warning: ruby 3.0.0_1 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 3.0.0_1, run:
  brew reinstall ruby
(base)
```

when I check the version use this command:

```
~/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open on  main! ⌚ 17:06:07
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]
(base)
```

how to make mac using the new version of ruby?

Comment: What returns `type ruby`?

Answer (score 0):

add path to `bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.0_1/bin:$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin:$CONDA_HOME/bin
```

make it work:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```